# Cache aside pattern on azure and redis cache

Tags: azure, caching

We are trying to implement cache aside pattern on azure. While reading data, we first check if data exist on cache, if it does, we serve it from cache. Otherwise we fetch it from database, populate cache and return it.
If cache is not accessible (due to some transient or non-transient issues), we ignore it.

But in case of update, we first update it in database and then delete the cache key. What should we do in case if cache is not accessible? To handle transient error we can implement retry strategy. If cache is not accessible even after retry, we should rollback our database transaction. Otherwise if cache comes back later, it would not be in sync with db. But while retrying, if somebody try to read this data, he will get a update value can later be rollbacked (if cache is not responding).

Thanks In Advance